# Access Main Form 'Enter Parameter Value'

Tags: ms-access, vba

Sorry, I’m pretty new at Access so I might not be using some terms correctly (or might not know some terms at all).

I’m encountering an ‘Enter Parameter Value’ error when I put my subform1 into my mainform. On subform1 I have a button that runs query1, query2, query3. These 3 queries query tables and also calculated fields that are located on subform1. Subform1’s data source is query4. When I press the button (with 3 queries), everything works.

Once I place that subform1 onto my mainform (so that my user can press the button to run the queries without entering the subform1) I receive an ‘Enter Parameter Value’ error. Query1, query2, query3 are unable to find those calculated fields located on subform1. For example the ‘enter parameter value’ error is as follows: Forms!subform1!calculatedfield1. I’ve tried changing the ‘location’ to things like: Me.subform1!calculatedfield or Form!mainform1!subform1!calculatedfield but I still receive that same parameter error. I could move the calculated fields to mainform1, which makes the queries work fine. But I would like to keep all of the calculated fields on the subform. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If your button is on the subform and you're referring to another control on the same subform then just use the `me!calculatedfield` to refer to that control.  i.e. no need to refer to subform since you're already there.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but I still received the parameter error. Just for clarification, the button will run query1 which looks like this: 

UPDATE table1 SET table1field = Forms!subform1!subform1calculatedfield

WHERE (((table1field) Between Forms!subform1!subform1calculatedfield

And Forms!subform1!subform1calculatedfield2)

Comment: Perhaps a better way to state the problem: 
I have the query open and the mainform1 open (with subform1 contained within it). When I run the query, it can't find the calculated fields on subform1. But subform1 is clearly open on mainform1.

Comment: And I'm guessing you're running that string with a dbs.execute or something like that.  Try  `"UPDATE table1 SET field = '" & forms!sub!field & "'"`

Comment: sorry, that didn't work either, thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

I always name subform container control different from the object it holds, such as ctrDetails. Then this works for me:

`Forms!Main!ctrDetails!fieldname`

However, my preference would be to run SQL statement in VBA. So code behind button could be like:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table1 SET table1field = " & Me.subform1calculatedfield & _
" WHERE table1field Between " & Me.subform1calculatedfield & " And " &  me.subform1calculatedfield2
```

Why do you need to save calculated data?